# Help, how can I properly notate this rhythm?

Tags: notation

this is the song

The intro/loop throughout is
F#m E A
Bm A/C# D
C#m E
A/E E

I was thinking like:
| F#m   F#m E A |  A Bm A/C# | D  D C#m E | E  A/E E F#m

But I don't know if that's a proper way to have it in bars

Does anybody have any suggestions on how can I notate this properly to show better timing?

Comment: If someone showed you the music, it would be of help to you, but not help any further than how many bars were shown. It would also be of very little help to any future readers of this question. Plus, it's hardly within the remit for this site. That's my reason to vtc.

Answer (score 1):

This is the rhythm of the intro:
[image]